# How to convert string to integer in a shell script?

Tags: shell

I have a file of 4GB in /var/tmp/test/dsk/file.1 in this path. Which
we can see through the Solaris Linux command as follows:

```
-bash-4.4# du -h /var/tmp/test/dsk/file.1 4.0G /var/tmp/test/dsk/file.1
```

I want only disk size so i did the following.

```
 disk=`du -h /var/tmp/test/dsk/file.1| awk '{print $1}'|tr -d '.G'`
```

which gives me the output as follows:

```
-bash-4.4# echo $disk 4.0
```

but I want to compare this disk size with the value 50 , for this first I need to convert above output to integer, but I'm failing to do
that, can anybody help in this, I have searched for this but not
 getting the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't see what could be the probem here :)
A tool like bc which accepts whatever format you may give:

```
[ $(bc <<< "$disk>=50") -eq 1 ]
```

Btw, you might want to convert your human readable size output to a simple numeric byte size with a function like:

```
# Converts human readable sizes into integer kilobyte sizes
# Usage numericSize="$(HumanToNumeric $humanSize)"
function HumanToNumeric {
    local value="${1}"

    local notation
    local suffix
    local suffixPresent
    local multiplier

    notation=(K M G T P E)
    for suffix in "${notation[@]}"; do
        multiplier=$((multiplier+1))
        if [[ "$value" == *"$suffix"* ]]; then
            suffixPresent=$suffix
            break;
        fi
    done

    if [ "$suffixPresent" != "" ]; then
        value=${value%$suffix*}
        value=${value%.*}
        # /1024 since we convert to kilobytes instead of bytes
        value=$((value*(1024**multiplier/1024)))
    else
        value=${value%.*}
    fi

    echo $value
}
```